# how can show symmetrical a view in android?

Tags: android, view, programmatically-created

I want to show a view symmetrical!(programmatically)

I try this class :

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "rotationY", 0, 180),
```

but I don't want use Animation;

Comment: What's wrong with using animations?